# deleting the name of the columnns and keep the rest of the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is like this:

```
 Code   345162  346199  347607  354144  355542  357052  357358  358632  361794  362237
Date                                        
2018-06-27  49.0    59.0    47.0    56.0    15.0    84.0    44.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
2018-06-28  42.0    75.0    44.0    46.0    90.0    138.0   68.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
```

And I want it to be like this one (i.e. drop the name of the columns 'Code'):

```
Date    345162  346199  347607  354144  355542  357052  357358  358632  361794  362237                              
2018-06-27  49.0    59.0    47.0    56.0    15.0    84.0    44.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
2018-06-28  42.0    75.0    44.0    46.0    90.0    138.0   68.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: `df.rename_axis(columns=None)`?

Comment: `df.columns.name = None` ? and btw, thats not a column name. thats the name of the columns

Answer (score 0):

Here try this

```
  df.rename(columns={'Code':" "},inplace=True)
Code   345162  346199  347607  354144  355542  357052  357358  358632  361794  362237
Date                                        
2018-06-27  49.0    59.0    47.0    56.0    15.0    84.0    44.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
2018-06-28  42.0    75.0    44.0    46.0    90.0    138.0   68.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Assuming you have a dataframe df, if you write this, then the name Code will be deleted (according to me). Hope it helps

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad